# eclipse rcp how to get extension's name?

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I have such extension element in my plugin.xml

how to get the name attribute of extension element ? I saw that IExtension interface does not provide a method to get name or get attribute.

```
<extension id="report" name="报表库" point="com.amarsoft.sysconfig.ep.dbtype">
    <functions>
       <function entryPage="com.amarsoft.sysconfig.report.EntryPage" id="ReportMng" name="报表设置">
       </function>
    </functions>
 </extension>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the name="foo" attribute of your extension with this code:

```
IConfigurationElement[] elements = Platform.getExtensionRegistry().getConfigurationElementsFor(EXTENSION_ID);

for (IConfigurationElement element : elements) {
    IExtension ext = (IExtension) element.getParent();
    System.out.println("name=" + ext.getLabel());
}
```